# Making my own AsynchronousSocketChannel

Tags: java, networking, asynchronous, nio, java-7

I'm making a program that needs to send encrypted data from one PC to another. Instead of explicitly having to encrypt/decrypt the data each time and then sending that by using an AsynchronousSocketChannel, I was wondering whether I could somehow extend the functionality of AsynchronousSocketChannel.write and AsynchronousSocketChannel.read to do this for me. It seems, though, that AsynchronousSocketChannel.write is a final method. Is there any way of making my own AsynchronousSocketChannel, or is this counter-intuitive?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it in your own class:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class EncryptedAsynchronousSocketChannel {
    private AsynchronousSocketChannel channel;
    public Future<Integer> read(ByteBuffer dst){
        return channel.read(dst);
    }
    public Future<Integer> write(ByteBuffer src){
        return channel.write(src);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but then I couldn't really take advantage of the already coded methods in AsynchronousSocketChannel. Is composition like this the only way of (easily) doing it?

Comment: just make methods that call methods of the same name in the private instance, modifying the parameters if needed. In java this is the only way that I know of

Comment: This is a relatively common problem when people try to improve the String class which is final. The other way is to extract rt.jar and modify the class to make it virtual, but I am assuming that you don't want to modify the java library.

Comment: I remember that with the old java.net you could actually subclass Socket and override some of its behaviour. I'm looking for something like that. I'll give your suggestion some more thought, though. Thanks.

Comment: I'd rather not modify the Java library. I was seeing if there was a legal and accepted way of doing this.